# Made In app purchase Using with Device token or Apple ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am implementing In-App Purchase in my app and test around the existing apps to get some ideas. But I found a scenario which I am quite confused on it.

I have installed an iOS app and purchased the particular levels. Later I uninstall this app, sign out from existing iTunes store account and sign in again with another apple id, then reinstall that app again (same app). Here i can again i need to purchase the particular levels.But my doubt is In-App purchase method we can use based on the purchase Apple ID or Device token ?

If the user can purchased with Apple ID ,then the user can login with another device they no need to purchased again but one user can purchase app and user can login to another users  Devices is the one problem..!why because another users no need to purchase.

And if we set the Device token, based on the in-app purchase user can only login that device only ,they can't login another devices with same Apple ID,here it is a problem.

I am quite confused on it... so is the purchased items tied on device if we use multiple apple ids on same device?

I understand that I can restore my purchased items on different devices using same apple id. But how about multiple apple id on multiple devices? If I have 2 apple id associated on an device, I use one of them purchased item, but later I use these 2 apple id login to another device, am I still need to pay again to download items I have purchased on previous device?

Please let me know if my questions are not clear... I hope someone can give some idea on sharing purchased items against different devices and apple ids.And which one use the in-app purchase.

Any suggestions and comments are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IAPs fall into two categories - consumable, and non-consumable.

Non-consumable purchases (purchase level 10-15 of a game, upgrade to pro, etc) are synced across devices by the system, and are restored by the system. They are tied to the Apple ID.

Consumable purchases (purchase 5 gold coins) are NOT synced or restored. Your application needs to remember that the purchase has been made, and store information about that so that a backup and restore correctly restores the user's state. If the user uninstalls and then reinstalls, they have lost any previous consumable purchases (but they will retain all non-consumable purchases, and your application can query for these). You can, of course, sync all information about consumable purchases to your own server, but you would then need to have the user create an account with you. This would allow you to sync consumables between devices.

The Device ID (which you can't get, anyway) has no relevance.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html for more discussion.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Airsource Ltd,here can i use the Apple ID?

Comment: There is no way on earth to get the customer's Apple ID. It's none of your business. Study the WWDC videos and the documentation. Your app is told that your customer made a purchase. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If the IAPs are non-consumables (or autorenewables) they can be 'restored' by the user (i.e. the app would execute a restoreCompletedTransactions or refreshReceipt).  I believe that the username/password log-in required to restoreCompletedTransactions (or refreshReceipt) must be the same username/password as the person who downloaded the app onto the device. Given that requirement, I still believe that a single 'purchaser' can share their single purchase of a non-consumable IAP on many devices.